# Is it possible to add multiple software sources at the same time?

Tags: software-sources

Is it possible to add multiple software sources through the command-line or the GUI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`add-apt-repository` accepts only one argument, but you can use:

```
for rep in {<ppa_1>,<ppa_2>,<ppa_3>}; do sudo add-apt-repository $rep; done
```

Comment: Picking this answer because it works and I can one-liner it, thanks!

Comment: Nice one Jacob.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using a script file.

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwibber-daily/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wrinkliez/ppasearch
```

Write these in a file (for example `script.sh`), make it executable and run it.